# sorting in real time firebase console panel

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I want to sort this data to display it in JSON arranged
that's my code when I upload my own data to a realtime  database

and there's an image result  that I want to arrange it

```
  HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1_UserName", a_name);
        map.put("2_phonenumber", phonenumber);
        map.put("3_Date", currentDate);
        map.put("4_Time", currentTime);
        map.put("5_Door_acess", check_Door_acess);
        map.put("6_StructuralCabling", check_StructuralCabling);
        map.put("7_Lightening", check_Lightening);
        map.put("8_check_FireSystem", check_FireSystem);
        map.put("9_AirConditioning", check_AirConditioning);
        map.put("10_Rack_01_Network", stringcheck_Rack_01_Network);
        map.put("11_PowerSourceLine1R_01", PowerSourceLine1R01);
        map.put("12_PowerSourceLine2_R01", PowerSourceLineR01);
        map.put("13_EarthingR01", EarthingR01);
        map.put("14_ofPDUsR01", ofPDUsR01editText_String11);
        map.put("15_ofOutlets_PDUR01", ofOutlets_PDUR01editText_String11);
        map.put("16_Horizontal_VerticalR01", Horizontal_VerticalR01);
        map.put("17_PPOSWOPPR01", PPOSWOPPR01);
        

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ammar").setValue(map);
```

and this image from consol
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase console is sorting the child keys exactly as expected.  They are being sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), or dictionary order, by string value.  It won't use the numeric values that you put at the start of each child.

If you need them to be sorted numerically by string prefix, you should pad the numeric values with 0 so the numbers are all the same width:

```
        map.put("01_UserName", a_name);
        map.put("02_phonenumber", phonenumber);
        map.put("03_Date", currentDate);
        map.put("04_Time", currentTime);
        map.put("05_Door_acess", check_Door_acess);
        map.put("06_StructuralCabling", check_StructuralCabling);
        map.put("07_Lightening", check_Lightening);
        map.put("08_check_FireSystem", check_FireSystem);
        map.put("09_AirConditioning", check_AirConditioning);
        map.put("10_Rack_01_Network", stringcheck_Rack_01_Network);
        map.put("11_PowerSourceLine1R_01", PowerSourceLine1R01);
        map.put("12_PowerSourceLine2_R01", PowerSourceLineR01);
        map.put("13_EarthingR01", EarthingR01);
        map.put("14_ofPDUsR01", ofPDUsR01editText_String11);
        map.put("15_ofOutlets_PDUR01", ofOutlets_PDUR01editText_String11);
        map.put("16_Horizontal_VerticalR01", Horizontal_VerticalR01);
        map.put("17_PPOSWOPPR01", PPOSWOPPR01);
```

Use more 0s if you expect larger numbers.